# java server with jetty memory leak issue

Tags: java, memory-leaks, server, jetty

I´m running this application with a Jetty server embedded. The application is slowly consuming more memory dispite the fact that the heap size does not change at all.

this is the command to start the application :

java -server -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

This is the chart from new relic with the RAM usage increase
[image]
it started using 1140MB and after 8 hours finished with 1290MB

This is the jvisualvm chart of the heap.
[image]

Any suggestions ?

[EDIT1] 
add dump https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gt1i9dhjtjauf0/gameserver-20160226-2107.zip?dl=0

[EDIT2]
Here are some notes from my current investigation

= How Monitor memory outside the heap
add parameters

```
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics
```

run command
jcmd 3322 VM.native_memory summary
@see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues

= Checking the default thread stack size 
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep ThreadStackSize

> > intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024
> >     [How to reclaim the memory used by a Java thread stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479214/how-to-reclaim-the-memory-used-by-a-java-thread-stack)

= Understand the max memory
Max memory = [-Xmx] + [-XX:MaxPermSize] + number_of_threads * [-Xss]
@see https://plumbr.eu/blog/memory-leaks/why-does-my-java-process-consume-more-memory-than-xmx

= Actions 
Reduce the size of the thread stacks. (In theory, you can go as low as 64K ...)

```
-XX:ThreadStackSize=256
```

Reduce the Minimum percentage of heap free after GC to avoid expansion.

```
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10
```

Now will continue monitoring ...

Comment: You might have forgotten to close a `Closeable` such as a `Connection`, a `Transaction`, `FileOutputStream` etc. It can also come from the usage of a native library.

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudDenoyelle, but I believe that would show at the heap usage chart, and the heap is allways bellow 400MB (sad)

Comment: It is impossible to say if you have a memory leak at all from the information provided.

Comment: what else should I provide ? pleae enlightme @MarkRotteveel !! :)

Comment: @hamilton.lima post an HPROF heap dump somewhere, then we can have a look at it

Comment: Impossible to say, all you have posted is an indication that your OS is claiming more memory, this could also be for cache that will be released if necessary.

Comment: @IngoKegel here is the HPROF https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gt1i9dhjtjauf0/gameserver-20160226-2107.zip?dl=0

Comment: sadly @MarkRotteveel whatever the SO is claiming is not been released

Comment: investigating http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756798/java-native-memory-usage thread stack seems to be the reason, as the heap does not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of different types of investigations, I came back to the [Eclipse Memory analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) and tried once more ...

But this time I decided to trust the leak report that was saying :

> One instance of "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl" loaded by
>   "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xc001d4f8" occupies 2.956.808
>   (21,05%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of
>   "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl" loaded by
>   "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xc001d4f8".

Then I shift my investigation the my DAO implementation, expecting that I forgot to close one or other EntityManager call. That wasn´t the case, all of then were with a nice close() method call after use.

Then I realize that the problem could be on hibernate itself as the problematic object were a **SessionFactory**Impl, so I changed my DAO implementation to clear Hibernate first level cache every time I create an Entity Manager, as I wasn´t able to find a way to disable it.

End of the day result = IT WORKED !! :) the memory changes a litle and come back after some minutes, but don´t grow in a crazy way anymore (1000MB in 24hours).

Here is the code I changed, hope it helps someone.

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    if( emf == null ){
        if (parameters == null) {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
        } else {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName, parameters);
        }
    } else {
        emf.getCache().evictAll();
    }

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    return em;
}
```

The key is here : **emf.getCache().evictAll();**